# SQL Server : while updating table, how come cannot delete is not updating row

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[BG_CalcNetPT_Loop]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @trancount int;
    SET @trancount = @@trancount;

    BEGIN TRY
        IF @trancount = 0
            begin transaction
        ELSE
            save transaction [BG_CalcNetPT_Loop];

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(255) = NULL;
    DECLARE @Cursor as CURSOR;
    DECLARE @UserId as int
    DECLARE @TicketId as nvarchar(50) -- BDBG_IssueId
    DECLARE @CreateDate as datetime

    BEGIN
        SET @Cursor = CURSOR FOR 

        -- select success bet which not yet calculate PT
        select distinct BDBG_IssueId, BDBG_UserId from tbl_BettingDetails_BG a WITH (NOLOCK)
        inner join tbl_Pt_BG b  WITH (NOLOCK) on a.BDBG_IssueId = b.pt_GameID
        where a.BDBG_Status = 1 and b.pt_isCalc = 0 and a.BDBG_Id = b.pt_TransID
        and DATEDIFF (DAY, a.BDBG_CreatedDate, GETDATE()) <= 7 and pt_SourceID <> 1104 
        order by BDBG_IssueId desc

        OPEN @Cursor
        FETCH NEXT FROM @Cursor INTO
            @TicketId
            ,@UserId
            --,@CreateDate

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0        
        BEGIN
            UPDATE 
                tbl_pt_BG 
            SET
                tbl_pt_BG.pt_UplinePresetPT_or_FixPT = (SELECT CASE 
                                WHEN (pt_fixpt > -1) 
                                    THEN pt_fixpt
                                WHEN (pt_UserType = 3) THEN
                                    (SELECT  isnull(BG_PTPercentage,0)
                                    from tbl_UserDetails_BG WITH(NOLOCK) where BG_UserID = @UserID)
                                ELSE
                                    pt_UplinePresetPT
                                END),

                    tbl_pt_BG.pt_downcomm2 = (SELECT CASE 
                                WHEN pt_UserType = 3 
                                    THEN BG_RollingCommission
                                WHEN pt_usertype_lvl1 = 3 
                                    THEN BG_RollingCommission
                                ELSE
                                    pt_downlinecomm
                            END) 
            FROM
                tbl_pt_BG AS A WITH (NOLOCK)
                --LEFT JOIN tbl_MemberFixPTSettingsBG AS B WITH (NOLOCK) ON A.pt_UserUplineID = B.AgentId --save in tbl_pt userid mean this agent take this user fix pt. CY 29/3/2020
                LEFT JOIN tbl_UserDetails_BG C WITH(NOLOCK) ON A.pt_userID=c.BG_UserId        
            WHERE
                pt_GameID = @TicketId and pt_SourceID = @UserID and pt_isCalc = 0

            FETCH NEXT FROM @Cursor INTO
            @TicketId
            ,@UserId
            --,@CreateDate
        END;

        CLOSE @Cursor ;
        DEALLOCATE @Cursor;
    END;

    lbexit:
        if @trancount = 0   
            commit;
    end try
    begin catch
        declare @error int, @message varchar(4000), @xstate int;
        select @error = ERROR_NUMBER(),
               @message = ERROR_MESSAGE(), 
               @xstate = XACT_STATE();
        if @xstate = -1
            rollback;
        if @xstate = 1 and @trancount = 0
            rollback
        if @xstate = 1 and @trancount > 0
            rollback transaction [BG_CalcNetPT_Loop];

            SELECT CASE WHEN @ErrorMessage IS NULL THEN 'error_unknown_error' ELSE  @ErrorMessage END AS errorMessage
            --SELECT CASE WHEN @ErrorMessage IS NULL THEN ERROR_MESSAGE() ELSE  @ErrorMessage END AS errorMessage

            INSERT INTO tbl_debug 
        (
            debug_sp,
            debug_ticketid,
            debug_text,
            debug_createddate
        )
        VALUES
        (
            'API_BG_Order_Transfer',
            CAST(@TicketId AS NVARCHAR(50)),
            CAST(ERROR_MESSAGE() AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),
            GETDATE()
        )
        raiserror ('API_BG_Order_Transfer: %d: %s', 16, 1, @error, @message) ;
    end catch   
END;
```

This code is a loop to `update tbl_pt_dg where pt_sourceid <> 1104` while this loop is executing, I'm trying to run this delete query

```
delete from tbl_Pt_BG 
where pt_GameID = '123' 
  and pt_isCalc = 1 
  and pt_SourceID = 1104
```

But this returns an error

> Transaction (Process ID 70) was deadlocked on lock | communication buffer resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.

[image]

Why while executing updating `tbl_pt_bg` is it locking the whole table? I can't wait for complete updating only delete the data.

Answer (score 0):

Cursors and loops should be avoiding because they are terrible slow. You should try thinking in set operations instead of loops. It's not surprising that you get this error, until the `UPDATE` from inside the `CURSOR` finishes, the `DELETE` is blocked. All that work is wrapped inside a `BEGIN TRANSACTION`, until the `COMMIT` is done, the `DELETE` will be blocked.